# Node.js exported function assign to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to save exported function to a variable to use `Promise.all`.
But when I assign the function to a variable, It runs. I want to prevent running when assigning function.

Example code

a.js

```
module.export = function say_hello(){ console.log('hello') }
```

b.js

```
var hello = require('./a.js');

var f1 = hello();
```

My expectation is don't running hello() and assigning to f1.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Why you don't do var f1 = require('./a.js')? or var f1 = hello

Comment: Just assign without calling the function: `var f1 = hello;`

Comment: In this example, I didn't write any code about `Promise`. Actually In a.js `say_hello()` returns `Promise` I want to push `say_hello()` functions to array and run `Promise.all()`. This is what I really want to do.

Comment: In real code, I have to pass args to say_hello().

Comment: `Promise.all([hello(params),hello(differentParams)]).then(() => { ... })`?

Comment: try 'module.exports' instead of 'module.export'

Answer (score 0):

a.js

```
module.exports = {
    hello: function say_hello() { console.log('hello'); }
}
```

b.js

```
var a = require ('./a.js')
a.say_hello();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` expects an array of promise parameters as input, so you must change your function to a `Promise` first:

```
module.export = function say_hello() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('hello');
        // whatever
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Then you will have a promise when you require it:

```
var hello = require('./a.js');
var f1 = hello();
Promise.all([f1,...])
```